# How to access internal array key [answer]?

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I'm having an array named `$questions_data` as follows:

```
Array
(
    [question_id] => 24440
    [question_parent_id] => 0
    [question_subject_id] => 12
    [question_topic_id] => 212
    [question_directions] => 
    [question_text] => &lt;b&gt;Length of the common chord of the circles &lt;i&gt;x&lt;/i&gt;&lt;sup&gt;2&lt;/sup&gt; + &lt;i&gt;y&lt;/i&gt;&lt;sup&gt;2&lt;/sup&gt; &amp;ndash; 2&lt;i&gt;x&lt;/i&gt; &amp;ndash; 4&lt;i&gt;y&lt;/i&gt; + 1 = 0 and &lt;i&gt;x&lt;/i&gt;&lt;sup&gt;2&lt;/sup&gt; + &lt;i&gt;y&lt;/i&gt;&lt;sup&gt;2&lt;/sup&gt; &amp;ndash; 4&lt;i&gt;x&lt;/i&gt; &amp;ndash; 2&lt;i&gt;y&lt;/i&gt; + 1 = 0 is&lt;/b&gt;
    [question_file] => 
    [question_description] => 
    [question_difficulty_type] => 1
    [question_has_sub_ques] => no
    [question_picked_individually] => no
    [question_appeared_count] => 0
    [question_manual] => 0
    [question_site_id] => 
    [question_created_staff_id] => 4e4078987c90dbf4ee477f480ad1b874
    [question_added_date] => 1326869354
    [question_updated_staff_id] => 706b8d833fbc4045ed046d500317bfa7
    [question_updated_date] => 1338439487
    [answer] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [answer_id] => 573997
                    [answer_text] => &lt;img src=&quot;/ckeditor_3.6.1//plugins/ckeditor_wiris/integration/showimage.php?formula=c836fa6f0f39de5b559b8b843c176c4f.png&quot; alt=&quot;�math xmlns=�http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML���msqrt��mn�14�/mn��/msqrt��/math�&quot; class=&quot;Wirisformula&quot; title=&quot;Double click to edit&quot; align=&quot;middle&quot;&gt;
                    [answer_file] => 
                    [answer_is_right] => 1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [answer_id] => 573998
                    [answer_text] => &lt;img src=&quot;/ckeditor_3.6.1//plugins/ckeditor_wiris/integration/showimage.php?formula=ac4e047dae78ab6f3155f0fab77153f2.png&quot; alt=&quot;�math xmlns=�http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML���msqrt��mn�15�/mn��/msqrt��/math�&quot; class=&quot;Wirisformula&quot; title=&quot;Double click to edit&quot; align=&quot;middle&quot;&gt;
                    [answer_file] => 
                    [answer_is_right] => 0
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [answer_id] => 573999
                    [answer_text] => &lt;img src=&quot;/ckeditor_3.6.1//plugins/ckeditor_wiris/integration/showimage.php?formula=6bcb45270a3cb70e2d8308173a4f5b03.png&quot; alt=&quot;�math xmlns=�http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML���mn�2�/mn��msqrt��mn�3�/mn��/msqrt��/math�&quot; class=&quot;Wirisformula&quot; title=&quot;Double click to edit&quot; align=&quot;middle&quot;&gt;
                    [answer_file] => 
                    [answer_is_right] => 0
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [answer_id] => 574000
                    [answer_text] => None of these&lt;br&gt;
                    [answer_file] => 
                    [answer_is_right] => 0
                )

        )

    [answer_id] => Array
        (
            [1] => 573997
            [2] => 573998
            [3] => 573999
            [4] => 574000
        )

    [previous_sub_ques_status] => no
)
```

I wan to access the internal array having key name ['answer']. I tried the following way but it didn't work for me. Can you help me in this regard, please?

```
if(!empty($questions_data)) {
          $questions_data['question_text']       = clear_p_tag(clear_question_data(html_entity_decode(stripslashes($questions_data['question_text']))));

          $questions_data['question_directions'] = clear_p_tag(clear_question_data(html_entity_decode(stripslashes($questions_data['question_directions']))));

          foreach ($question_data['answer'] as $val){
            $val['answer_text'] = clear_p_tag(clear_question_data(html_entity_decode(stripslashes($val['answer_text']))));
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

This reads

```
foreach ($question_data['answer'] as $val){
```

instead of

```
foreach ($questions_data['answer'] as $val){
```

There's a missing S